# C++ Mysql querying ascii format

Tags: c++, mysql, ascii, collation

I am using linux machine. I need to query a xml text from mysql with c++ but i need the query as ascii format. I tried a lot of collation includes `latin5_turkish_ci`, `utf8` etc but every time when i query the string turkish characters won't come truely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this query before any kind of utf8 insert.

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. After Mysql connection init, "mysql_query(connection,"SET NAMES latin5");" solved my problem.